# How can I use loop functionality in twig template?

Tags: symfony, loops, twig, drupal-8, theming

I want to use a looping functionality in `region.html.twig` file to I can
wrap elements that outputted from `{{ content }}` section.

Defult `region.html.twig`

```
{% if content %}
  <div class="Parent">
    {{ content }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

The schematic generated Output:

```
<div class="Parent">
  Item_1
  Item_2
  Item_3
</div>
```

I try to use below code to create a loop and add a wrapper around of each `Item` outputted from `{{ content }}`:

My code:

```
{% if content %}
  <div class="Parent"> 
    {% for item in items %}
      <div class="child-wrapper">{{ item.content }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

The Final outpute that I want to achive:

```
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="child-wrapper">Item_1</div>
  <div class="child-wrapper">Item_2</div>
  <div class="child-wrapper">Item_3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code looks fine...what isn't working?

Comment: @Jason Roman: Thanks for your reply, but whatever I try I can't get any result!!!

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani any errors or Excetption ? try to inspect with {% dump content items %} to see whats inside and how they structured

Comment: Why don't you try showing is what your code is currently outputting?

Comment: as said by @JasonRoman, we need more detail about your datas and the output you got

Comment: @t-n-y: Thanks, When I use loop nothing shows up.

Comment: show your entity, tell us what you have in your database ... we need more infos to help. What is item, what is content ?

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani try {% dump ... %} as i mendtioned above right before the first if-statement and show us the output or make a screen

Comment: @V-Light: when I add `{% dump content items %}` , "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." Error message shows up.

Comment: @Jason Roman: when I add {% dump content items %} , "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." Error message shows up.

Comment: Should be `{{ dump(content, items) }}` and you need to use the debug URL in Symfony, as in append `app_dev.php` to your URL. If you use in prod you will get an error, since dump is not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

```
If your data is: content = [1, 2, 3, ... , 100]

   Then write
    {% if content %}
      <div class="Parent"> 
        {% for item in content %}
          <div class="child-wrapper">{{ item }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}

If your data is array of assotiated arrays like this: 
content = [
    ['content' => 1],   
    ['content' => 2],   
]

   Then write
    {% if content %}
      <div class="Parent"> 
        {% for item in content %}
          <div class="child-wrapper">{{ item.content }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
```